# Quantmod, getSymbols, Extracting Close Price in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I have a string of tickers that I'm trying to get data for using Quantmod.  My list is long and there are some bad tickers so I use the incorporate the try function.

I'm having trouble using the Cl function from Quantmod.  As far as I can tell it should work - but I'm sure I have a small problem with my syntax.

Code:

```
tickers = c("IBM","GM")  #This is an example for purpose here
stock_data <- lapply(tickers, function(tickers), try(getsymbols(tickers,
    auto.assign=FALSE)))
close_prices <- do.call(merge,Cl(stock_data))
```

stock_data comes back as a list of xts objects identified by the ticker with the rows of each element as a date value and the columns a series of ticker-related data (open, close, etc.).

close_prices should be a list or data frame of only the closing price column of all tickers (i.e, the closing price column from IBM, the closing price column from GM, etc.).

When I apply the do.call (which I have in various permutations - none of them correct) I get an error that tells me their are no column values within the xts object that contain "close" - which just isn't the case.  For each xts element (identified as "IBM" and "GM" in this case) there is a column named "XXX.close" (e.g., IBM.Close, GM.Close).  I don't know why I can't get the syntax right or get Cl to see the close columns.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

**** Edit/UPDATE ***

My list stock_data for the sample vector has the following structure:

```
str(stock_data)
List of 2
 $ :An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-05/2015-12-07 containing:
  Data: num [1:234, 1:6] 161 160 157 156 158 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "IBM.Open" "IBM.High" "IBM.Low" "IBM.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
  ..$ src    : chr "yahoo"
  ..$ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-12-09 16:21:31"
 $ :An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-05/2015-12-07 containing:
  Data: num [1:234, 1:6] 35 34.4 35.2 36.1 36.2 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "GM.Open" "GM.High" "GM.Low" "GM.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
  ..$ src    : chr "yahoo"
  ..$ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-12-09 16:21:31"
```

The structure is the same for the actual vector - it is just longer with more dimensions.

Comment: what about `do.call(merge,lapply(stock_data,Cl))`? Note that you can replace `merge` by `cbind`: `do.call(cbind,lapply(stock_data,Cl))`

Comment: @agstudy : that works on my sample list but when I run my big list through it fails.  I get the error:  'Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...):  subscript out of bounds:  no column name containing "Close"' - but when I look in my global environment is absolutely shows IBM.Close, etc.  I don't know why it would work for a small list and not a large list - unless if when it fails on a bad ticker something happens.

Comment: The error is clear one of your xts don't have a close. to check which one , you can do `sapply(stock_data,function(x) sum('Close' %in% names(x)))`

Comment: @agstudy - I ran your code and it came back with all 0s.  That suggests if I understand right that it isn't seeing close in any of the columns.  I also ran it after running my code on the two element sample ticker vector above and also go zeros.  I'm going to edit and type in my str(stock_data) in the question above - maybe I am mis-reading something about the structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
  library(plyr)
  library(quantmod)
  stocks <- c("IBM","GM")
  data.env <- new.env()

  ### here we use l_ply so that we don't double save the data
  ### getSymbols() does this already so we just want to be memory efficient
  ### go through every stock and try to use getSymbols()
  l_ply(stocks, function(sym) try(getSymbols(sym,env=data.env),silent=T))

  ### now we only want the stocks that got stored from getSymbols()
  ### basically we drop all "bad" tickers
  stocks <- stocks[stocks %in% ls(data.env)]

  ### now we just loop through and merge our good stocks
  ### if you prefer to use an lapply version here, that is also fine
  ### since now we are just collecting all the good stock xts() objects
  data <- xts()
  for(i in seq_along(stocks)) {
    symbol <- stocks[i]
    data <- merge(data, Ad(get(symbol,envir=data.env)))
  }
```

Comment: -Thanks for this.  I'm going through it in detail and it is taking a bit of time.  It is kind of crazy that we need to go through such work arounds to handle something a simple as a bad ticker.  Could you explain the code in a bit of detail?  I am not that familiar with plyr but did some looking and there are things I couldn't completely figure out (e.g., l_ply doesn't save anything according to documentation but cleary it save the data collected through getSymbols in data.env, etc.).  Thanks.

Comment: yes they help very much.  Thanks.  Just one quick question on the last line.  why is the syntax include a get function?  shouldn't the Quantmod Ad take care of get? Thx.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 you need to retrieve the xts() object. get() retrieves the xts object of the stock with symbol. Then Ad() will pull the adjusted close price. do you mind accepting this is the right answer if it achieves your goal

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware of the incredible useful quantmod add-on "qmao" ? It makes a function "PF" (for price frame ) available, which does exactly what you are looking for if I correctly understand your question. ( there is also a function "RF" which does the same with returns instead of prices )
example:

```
library(quantmod)
library(qmao)

tickers = c('AMZN','AAPL','MSFT')
getSymbols(tickers,from='2005-01-01') 
prices <- PF(tickers, silent=TRUE) # by default adj. closing prices are used, but you can select any column. open, high ...

> head(prices)
            AMZN     AAPL     MSFT
2005-01-03 44.52 4.209303 21.03721
2005-01-04 42.14 4.252533 21.11588
2005-01-05 41.77 4.289778 21.06868
2005-01-06 41.05 4.293103 21.04508
2005-01-07 42.32 4.605692 20.98214
2005-01-10 41.84 4.586404 21.08441
```

For more information check: `?PF` or ?makePriceFrame (PF is an alias for makePriceFrame)

Comment: I was not aware.  I will check it out.  Thank you!

Comment: I found and installed the add on from R Forge but cannot find any documentation on the functions on line or with R Studio.  Can you direct me to some?  Thank you.

Comment: If the package is installed correctly entering `?PF` or `?makePriceFrame` shall display the online help for this function.